# initdb: error: could not create directory “./PostgreSQL”: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, windows

It is my first time setting up a database (postgresql 12) on my windows 8.1

It's been 4 days of struggling to find a solution from many related questions in this field but not successful to find the answer (whether I didn't understand them or they didn't work in my case).

So, here, I will explain, step by step, what I did and what errors I got in each phase (They may not affect each other but I mention all the errors):

When I installed PostgreSQL as an administrator, at the end of the process I got this error: "Failed to load SQL modules into the database cluster" I reinstalled twice but it seemed to pop up every time. Here, in this post, I found somebody who faced the same problem, but I didn't technically understand what is the solution, unfortunately: Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster during PostgreSQL Installation. thus, I just skipped it and everything seemed okay.

Then I set the PATH in advanced system settings-->Environment variables (in both user variables and system variables boxes) like this: ";C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib"

After this step, I opened a terminal using ctrl+R and entered cmd.exe then entered these codes:

```
> cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin
> initdb -U postgres -A password -E utf8 -W -D .\PostgreSQL\12\data
```

Here I got this message:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "pc".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_United States.1252".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

Enter new superuser password:
Enter it again:
```

After entering my password, I got this error:

```
    The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "pc".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_United 
States.1252".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

Enter new superuser password:
Enter it again:

creating directory /PostgreSQL/12/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... windows
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Asia/Tehran
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D ^"^\PostgreSQL^\12^\data^" -l logfile start
```

But when entering the suggested code (no matter using logfile or other files names) I keep getting this message:

```
waiting for server to start....Access is denied.
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

On the other hand, when I tried pgAdmin4 browser interface, when I right-clicked on servers-->create-->server in the popped up window I filled these fields:

On General tab I filled the "Name" box as "dbserver" my "Username" was set as "postgres", then on Connection tab I set "Host" to "localhost" and "Password" as what I set before.

Here is the error I got:

```
Unable to connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is 
the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not 
connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" 
(127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can somebody help me out with this problem?

Thank you

Comment: First where did you get the Postgres software from?  Two the link to the post you mention is not live. Third when you did the initdb where you the system admin user?

Comment: Hello @Adrian Klaver, I got PostgreSQL from this site: https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ For the third question, how can I check whether I was admin user or not?

Comment: Did you follow the instruction here [install](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/postgresql/installation-getting-started/installation-guide-installers/12/index.html)? Also how answers to the other questions?

Comment: Thank you @Adrian Klaver, I reinstalled as an administer, now it creates the directory, but when I use the suggested code to start the database server, I get the error "waiting for server to start....Access is denied." I edited the above post to refer to its detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer, and I want to share it. I opened the postgres.conf file and comment out logging_collector, log_directory, and log_destination. I saved the file.

Then in the terminal, I typed the suggested piece of code like below:

```
pg_ctl -D ^"^\PostgreSQL^\12^\data^" start
```

And the server started.

Now in the pgAdmin4 browser, the problem is gone too.